# Filtering a list using checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, find

I have a list of movies as well their ratings. At the top of my page I have a form that gives a list of checkboxes that shows each available rating (G, PG-13, etc). Once a user clicks a checkbox(es) and hits submit I just want the selected movies to show up.

In my index method I have an instance variable called `@filtered_ratings` that collects the keys from the checked movies. My idea was to alter `@movies` in my controller using the find method and matching the keys from `@filtered_ratings` to the list of movies. However, I think I've been doing this incorrectly as I can't get it to work. I've tried several ways such as `@movies=Movie.find(params[:id] = @filtered_ratings)` but I know this is incorrect. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your checkbox form is something like:

```
<%= form_tag method: (blah), url: (blah) do %>
   <%= check_box_tag 'ratings[]', "R" %>
   <%= check_box_tag 'ratings[]', "PG" %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'ratings[]', "PG-13" %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

you would get params[:ratings] = ["R", "PG"] if say the first two boxes were checked. So, in the controller you could just do

```
Movie.where("rating IN (?)", params[:ratings])
```

. This assumes your movies have a 'rating' attribute.

Comment: your assumption is right; however, I just use a block to generate everything. Also, when I altered my controller to your suggested code it completely removes the list of movies. Lastly, we were explicitly told that `find` would be the easiest way to do this.

Comment: If you absolutely have to use 'find', you could instead use Movie.find(:all, conditions: ["rating IN (?)", params[:ratings]]), but this results in the same SQL query. If this code removes the list of movies, params[:ratings] is probably either nil or empty. What values do you see in the params hash?

Comment: At the top of my index page I put `=params[:ratings].keys` and the values being rendered were the values of the checked boxes. So I am certain the params hash is not empty.

Comment: What's the output of params[:ratings].keys

Comment: It is the value of the checked boxes. For instance if I check G, PG, and PG-13 `=params[:ratings].keys` returns `["G", "PG", "PG-13"]`

Comment: And, using this, what code are you running to get the movies from the db?

Comment: Currently I am just using `@movies = Movie.all` in my controller but I would like to alter this to find just the movies with the ratings that are checked.

Comment: If your movie records have rating attributes storing the actual rating strings ("PG", "G", etc.), I can't see why `Movie.where("rating IN (?)", params[:ratings].keys)` would return nothing.

Comment: `Movie.where("rating IN (?)", params[:ratings].keys)` works whereas `Movie.where("rating IN (?)", params[:ratings])` does not. Thank you so much!! Just curious what the piece of code `IN (?)` does? I've never seen that.

Comment: "rating IN (?)" is a SQL condition. Rails replaces the question mark with the second parameter, an array in this case. So SQL will return all records that have a 'rating' that is any one of the values in the array.

Comment: Also did `@movies = Movie.where(:rating => @filtered_ratings)` which works as well

Comment: thanks, I was stuck at the same place too. I've been at it for the last 5  hours. Was trying the same things.