# How to filter results by clicking on checkbox in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a newbie in ruby on rails it's also my first ruby application.
I want to filter results by clicking on checkbox which is coming from
the database and showing on the right side of my webpage, the checkbox
is lying on the left side. In the below I attached my webpage's
screenshot for easy understanding.

Anyone can help me, please, how can I solve this issue?

My Controller file code:**resumes_controller.rb**

```
class ResumesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :recruiter!
  def resumes
   @resume = Jobseeker.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10).order('jobseeker_id DESC')
  end
end
```

My view file code: **resumes.html.erb**

```
 <%= form_for :jobseekers,url: resumes_path(@jobseekers), action: :update, method: :post  do |f| %>
   <div>
      <label for="Title">Education</label>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <%= check_box("tag", {checked: true}) %>Masters
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <%= check_box("tag", {checked: true}) %>Bachelor
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <%= check_box("tag", {checked: true}) %>Associates
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <%= check_box("tag", {checked: true}) %>Diploma
      </div>
      <a href="#">More</a>
  </div>
<% end %>

<!-- item1 -->

    <% @resume.each do | res| %>
    <div class="job-item bio-card">
      <div class="employer-information">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li class="employ-name">
              <a href="<%= view_profile_path(:jobseeker_id => res.jobseeker_id) %>">

                <%= res.first_name %> <%= res.last_name %></a> <span>- <%= res.current_address %></span>
            </li>
            <li><%= res.institute_name %></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <% if res.attach_resume.nil? %>
        <div class="col-sm-6 employ-pdf-box">
          <div class="employ-pdf">
            <i class="fa fa-file-powerpoint-o icon"></i>
            <h3>Empty</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <% else %>
        <div class="col-sm-6 employ-pdf-box">
          <a href="<%= res.attach_resume.resume %>"target="_blank">
            <div class="employ-pdf">
              <i class="fa fa-file-powerpoint-o icon"></i>
              <h3><%= res.first_name %> <%= res.last_name %>.pdf</h3>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
       <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<!-- End item1 -->
```

Comment: You need theoretical answer or code.  The question is very broad.  Also, you have not mentioned what front-end technology you are using .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering a list using checkboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941389/filtering-a-list-using-checkboxes)

Comment: I added my controller and view file codes now, I need answer by code @WandMaker

Comment: Question is too broad, but I'll try help anyways. Instead of always checking your checkboxes: `, {checked: true}` make this value depending on a param, so the user selection is kept across page refreshes. Simply filter Jobseeker.where(education: params[:education_ids]) results if a user has selected some of the options.